# No response to the Deezer API request "editorial/0/charts"

Tags: android, sdk, deezer

I use the Deezer API v0.10.10 to request `editorial/0/charts`, but it does not work. There is no response and exception.

```
DeezerRequest request = new DeezerRequest("editorial/0/charts");
AsyncDeezerTask task = new AsyncDeezerTask(mDeezerConnect,
                    new JsonRequestListener() {
                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(final Object result, final Object requestId) {
                            PaginatedList<Track> resp = (PaginatedList<Track>) result;
                    });
task.execute(request);
```

I use the Deezer API v0.10.10 and Android 4.0 (API 14) or greater.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your sample code that you're using Deezer SDK for Android 0.10.10.

The JsonRequestListener is able to parse many common request but does not parse all available API requests yet, and the one you are using is not handled properly yet. Unfortunately there is a slight error in this version of the SDK, causing the lack of callback you experienced.

Here is a sample listener you can use to parse the API's response for this particular request :

```
RequestListener listener = new RequestListener() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object requestId) {

        List<Track> tracks;
        List<Artist> artists;
        List<Album> albums;
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

            tracks = (PaginatedList<Track>) JsonUtils
                    .deserializeObject(json.optJSONObject("tracks"));
            artists = (PaginatedList<Artist>) JsonUtils
                    .deserializeObject(json.optJSONObject("artists"));
            albums = (PaginatedList<Album>) JsonUtils
                    .deserializeObject(json.optJSONObject("albums"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tracks = Collections.emptyList();
            artists = Collections.emptyList();
            albums = Collections.emptyList();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("Json",
                "Parsed " + tracks.size() + " tracks, " + albums.size()
                        + " albums and " + artists.size() + " artists");
    }

    @Override
    public void onOAuthException(OAuthException e, Object requestId) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object requestId) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object requestId) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeezerError(DeezerError e, Object requestId) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
};

DeezerRequest request = new DeezerRequest("editorial/0/charts");
AsyncDeezerTask task = new AsyncDeezerTask(mConnect, mListener);
task.execute(request);
```